# Msft_Volume: multiple records for 'D:'

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, diskmanagement

Im getting some strange results for Msft_Volume query

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Msft_Volume"  -Namespace Root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage
```

I see 'D' drive six times! I there any explanation and which one is real?

```
AllocationUnitSize   : 4096
DedupMode            : 4
DriveLetter          : D
DriveType            : 3
FileSystem           : NTFS
FileSystemLabel      : DATA
FileSystemType       : 14
HealthStatus         : 0
ObjectId             : {1}\\DELLCSPRHV02\root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/Providers_v2\WSP_Volume.ObjectId="{60fd5c97-6507-4543-99f1-daf47227f21e}:VO:\\?\Volume{0074c0a4-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\"
OperationalStatus    : {2}
PassThroughClass     :
PassThroughIds       :
PassThroughNamespace :
PassThroughServer    :
Path                 : \\?\Volume{0074c0a4-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\
Size                 : 162522984448
SizeRemaining        : 48756031488
UniqueId             : \\?\Volume{0074c0a4-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\
PSComputerName       : DELL590HV12



AllocationUnitSize   : 4096
DedupMode            : 4
DriveLetter          : D
DriveType            : 3
FileSystem           : NTFS
FileSystemLabel      : DATA
FileSystemType       : 14
HealthStatus         : 0
ObjectId             : {1}\\DELLCSPRHV02\root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/Providers_v2\WSP_Volume.ObjectId="{60fd5c97-6507-4543-99f1-daf47227f21e}:VO:\\?\Volume{2d4b4fad-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\"
OperationalStatus    : {2}
PassThroughClass     :
PassThroughIds       :
PassThroughNamespace :
PassThroughServer    :
Path                 : \\?\Volume{2d4b4fad-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\
Size                 : 162522984448
SizeRemaining        : 128554635264
UniqueId             : \\?\Volume{2d4b4fad-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\
PSComputerName       : DELL590HV12



AllocationUnitSize   : 4096
DedupMode            : 4
DriveLetter          : D
DriveType            : 3
FileSystem           : NTFS
FileSystemLabel      : DATA
FileSystemType       : 14
HealthStatus         : 0
ObjectId             : {1}\\DELLCSPRHV02\root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/Providers_v2\WSP_Volume.ObjectId="{60fd5c97-6507-4543-99f1-daf47227f21e}:VO:\\?\Volume{4491b922-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\"
OperationalStatus    : {2}
PassThroughClass     :
PassThroughIds       :
PassThroughNamespace :
PassThroughServer    :
Path                 : \\?\Volume{4491b922-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\
Size                 : 162522984448
SizeRemaining        : 50788323328
UniqueId             : \\?\Volume{4491b922-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\
PSComputerName       : DELL590HV12
```

full output: https://pastebin.com/qRiCEUL3

There are no spanned volumes.

The sum of all SizeRemaining = 535GB

The only second disk has correct SizeRemaining

```
Size                 : 162522984448
SizeRemaining        : 128554635264
128554635264/(1024*1024*1024) = 119.725833892822 Gb
```

[image]